# cakephp Router::parseExtensions('ics') doesn't work properly

Tags: parsing, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to create an ical-file.

So I set `Router::parseExtensions('ics')` in `router.php`.
I created a folder `ics` in `app/views/layouts` and a `default.ctp` with this content

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/calendar');
    echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

In my reservationsController I created a `ical()` action and created a `ical.ctp` in `/app/views/reservations/ics/`.

So, if I'm trying to access `http://localhost/reservations/ical/1.ics` I get an error:

```
Error: The view for ReservationsController::ical() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\app\views\reservations\ical.ctp
```

So I'm a bit confused about the error-message. Why does it search the `ical.ctp` in `app\views\reservations\` and not in `app\views\reservations\ics\`?

When I'm using another extension like `.xml` the error message looks like this:

```
Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\app\views\reservations\xml\ical.ctp
```

Why does xml work and ics don't? What went wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I've just finished dealing with this situation myself. I'd been trying to get a `csv` extension to display, and I was also getting the "missing view" error.

Everything was in place; I had my `/app/views/layouts/csv/default.ctp` and `/app/views/users/csv/export.ctp` view files set up. I had `Router::parseExtensions('csv');` at the top of my `/app/config/routes.php` file.

Turns out, what I had forgotten was to add the RequestHandler component to my controller's components array: `var $components = array('RequestHandler');`.

Once I did that everything worked perfectly.

So if you've stumbled upon this question because you're having the same issue, check to be sure you're loading the RequestHandler component fixes things for you...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same trouble creating the ics example @ http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/11/21/serving-views-as-files-in-cake2

Needed quite a while to figur out that this seems to be a cake bug and opend a ticket for it :)
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/2565-cakeresponse-is-missing-icalendar-and-not-responding-as-documented
Hopefully this will be resolved soon.

PS: I also posted a workaround / quickfix for this until it is fixed in the core.